# Sasaki Metric for Finsler Manifolds

Tags: differential-geometry, manifolds, riemannian-geometry, tangent-bundle, finsler-geometry

**Question: is there a "generalized" Sasaki metric for Finsler manifolds?**

More directly, let $(M,F)$ be a Finsler manifold with the Cartan connection. 
Is there a Finsler manifold $(TM,\hat{F})$ such that if $(M,F)$ is actually Riemannian, then $\hat{F}$ reduces to the Sasaki metric?

If there is more than one, which might not surprise me, which is considered "natural" and why?

So far, I've found some sparse literature (e.g. [Finsler Geometry and Natural Foliations on the Tangent Bundle by Bejancu and Farran](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0034487706800443)), but would like others' thoughts.