# Definition of Hölder Space on Manifold

Tags: partial-differential-equations, manifolds, holder-spaces

Can anyone point me to a reference for the definition of Hölder spaces for manifolds (with boundary)? Every paper I have looked at says these are "defined in the ordinary way" and no one says what that way is.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Related: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1321060/169085

Answer (score 3):

The local version of the Hölder condition can be defined the same way integral regularity can be defined; see e.g. Ruelle's *Elements of Differentiable Dynamics and Bifurcation Theory*, pp.138-151, App. B for a convenient summary and Bonic & Frampton's "Smooth Functions on Banach Manifolds" for a more general study. This seems to me to be the "ordinary way".

For the sake of completeness, here is an outline (the above references cover Banach manifolds as well):

Let $\mathbb{E}$ and $\mathbb{F}$ be locally convex topological vector spaces, let $U\subseteq \mathbb{E}$ be open, and fix $(q,\theta)\in\mathbb{Z}_{\geq0}\times ]0,1]$. Call a function $f:U\to \mathbb{F}\,\,\,$ **$\theta$-Hölder** at $x\in U$ if there is an open subset $x\in U_x\subseteq U$ such that

$$\exists C=C(U_x)\in\mathbb{R}_{>0},\forall y,z\in U_x: |f(y)-f(z)|_{\mathbb{F}}\leq C\, |y-z|_{\mathbb{E}}^\theta.$$

Call $f:U\to \mathbb{F}$ **locally $\theta$-Hölder** if it is Hölder at any point of $U$. Denote by $C^{(q,\theta)}(U;\mathbb{F})$ the collection of all locally $\theta$-Hölder functions from $U$ to $\mathbb{F}$.

Similarly, call $f:U\to \mathbb{F}\,\,$ a **$C^{(q,\theta)}$ function** if it is $q$ times continuously differentiable and its $q$-th derivative is locally $\theta$-Hölder, that is,

$$D^qf:U\to \operatorname{Hom}_{\text{TVS}}(\mathbb{E}^{\otimes q};\mathbb{F})$$

is a continuous map, with the target space being the locally convex topological vector space of all continuous $q$-linear maps from $\underbrace{\mathbb{E}\times \mathbb{E}\times\cdots\times \mathbb{E}}_{q \text{ many}}\,$ to $\mathbb{F}$ with norm

$$\Vert B\Vert_{\mathbb{F}\leftarrow\mathbb{E}^{\otimes q}}=\sup\{|B(x_1,x_2,...,x_q)|_{\mathbb{F}}\,\,\,|\,\,\,x_1,x_2,...,x_q\in \mathbb{E}, |x_1|_{\mathbb{E}}\leq 1,|x_2|_{\mathbb{E}}\leq 1,...,|x_q|_{\mathbb{E}}\leq 1\}.$$

Defining a total order on $\mathbb{Z}_{\geq0}\times]0,1]$ by

$$(k,\alpha)< (l,\beta) \iff [k=l \text{ and } \alpha<\beta] \text{ xor } [k<l],$$

thus in particular

\begin{align*}
(0,0)\leq (0,\theta)
\leq (0,1)<&(1,0)
\leq (1,\theta)\leq (1,1)
<(2,0)\cdots \\
< &(q,0)\leq (q,\theta)\leq (q,1)
<(q+1,0)<\cdots,
\end{align*}

we have that if $(q_1,\theta_1)\leq(q_2,\theta_2)$, then $C^{(q_2,\theta_2)}\subseteq C^{(q_1,\theta_1)}$.

For the manifold case, let $M$ and $N$ be  $C^\infty$ (wlog; see [Motivations of studying $C^r$ manifolds when $r<\infty$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2892513/169085)) manifolds of dimension $\dim(M)=m\in\mathbb{Z}_{\geq0}$ and $\dim(N)=n\in\mathbb{Z}_{\geq0}$, respectively. Then call a function $f:M\to N\,\,$ a **$C^{(q,\theta)}$ function** if

$$\forall (U,\phi)\in\operatorname{Chart}(M),\forall (V,\psi)\in \operatorname{Chart}(N): f(U)\cap V\neq\emptyset\implies\psi\circ f\circ \phi^{-1}\in C^{(q,\theta)}(\phi(U); \mathbb{R}^n).$$

---

It seems to me global Hölder conditions are varied; in any event one needs some extra conditions; e.g. if $M$ is compact one can optimize the constants of $f$ coming from local Hölder conditions over a finite cover. Another common alternative in the compact case is to fix a $C^\infty$ Riemannian metric on $M$ and an  isometric embedding $M\hookrightarrow \mathbb{R}^{d(M)}$ for some $d(M)\in\mathbb{Z}_{\gg0}$ and use the extrinsic Euclidean distance to define global Hölder continuity (see e.g. Brin & Stuck's *Introduction  to Dynamical Systems* (p.143), or Brin's "Hölder Continuity of Invariant Distributions" for this perspective (though in these works local Hölder estimates are all that is needed)).

Alternatively one can choose a $C^0$ fiberwise norm $\mathfrak{q}$ on $M$ (in particular one can take a $C^\infty$ Riemannian metric) and consider the (generalized) intrinsic distance function associated to it. Explicitly, if $\mathfrak{q}:TM\to\mathbb{R}_{\geq0}$ is continuous such that $\forall x\in M: \mathfrak{q}_x=\mathfrak{q}|_{T_xM}:T_xM\to \mathbb{R}_{\geq0}$ is a norm, then

\begin{align*}
d_\mathfrak{q}:M\times M&\to [0,\infty],\,\,\\(x,y)&\mapsto\begin{cases} \inf\{L_\mathfrak{q}(\gamma)\,|\, \gamma:([0,1],0,1)\to (M,x,y) \text{ is piecewise }C^\infty\},&\text{ if } x,y \text{ are in the same connected component}\\
\infty&\text{, otherwise}
\end{cases},
\end{align*}

where  $L_\mathfrak{q}(\gamma)=\int_0^1 \mathfrak{q}_{\gamma(t)}(\gamma'(t))\, dt$ is the length structure associated to $\mathfrak{q}$. For the global Hölder continuity of a function $f:M\to N$ one would need to fix a $C^0$ fiberwise norm on both $M$ and $N$. In this case one could define $f:M\to N$ to be **globally $\theta$-Hölder** (w/r/t fiberwise norms $\mathfrak{q}^M$ and $\mathfrak{q}^N$) if

$$\exists C\in\mathbb{R}_{>0},\forall y,z\in M: d_{\mathfrak{q}^N}(f(y),f(z))\leq C\, d_{\mathfrak{q}^M}(y,z)^\theta.$$

Defining $C^{(q,\theta)}(M;N)$ for $q\geq 1$ becomes even less canonical; however see Hebey & Robert's "Sobolev Spaces on manifolds" (p.389) (or Lee & Parker's "The Yamabe Problem" (p.44)) for the case when $N=\mathbb{R}$ and $M$ is endowed with a $C^\infty$ Riemannian metric.

---

Even though I have never seen this one used, a final probable definition would be via a natural metric (e.g. the Sasaki metric, see e.g. [Sasaki Metric for Finsler Manifolds](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2406342/169085), [Riemannian metric of the tangent bundle](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/52509/169085), [Is there a natural connection on $TM$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4356876/169085), [Why is the Sasaki metric natural?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2373967/169085), [Completeness of the tangent bundle of riemannian manifold](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3116727/169085)) on the tangent bundle $TM$ induced by a $C^1$ Riemannian metric on $M$; one could then e.g. define $f:M\to N$ **globally $C^{(1,\theta)}$** if ($f:M\to N$ is globally $\theta$-Hölder continuous and) $Tf:TM\to TN$ exists and is globally $\theta$-Hölder continuous with respect to the induced natural metrics. Adapting this idea to jet bundles one could define globally $C^{(q,\theta)}$  functions as functions whose $q$-th jets exist and are globally $\theta$-Hölder continuous (see e.g. [Higher-order derivatives in manifolds](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/123007/169085), [Higher order differential on a manifold, connections](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/600226/169085), https://mathoverflow.net/q/222020/66883).

Alternatively, one could fix $C^q$ Riemannian metrics on $M$ and $N$ and consider the global $C^{(q,\theta)}$ regularity of $f$ by saying that for each $i\in\mathbb{0,1,...,q}:$$T^if: T^iM\to T^iN$ exists and is globally $\theta$-Hölder continuous w/r/t the Sasaki distances on $T^iM$ and $T^iN$ induced by the induced Sasaki metrics. Admittedly it's not clear to me, as I'm writing this answer, if these constructions are useful. Here I'm considering $T$ as a monad $T:\text{Man}^\infty\to \text{Man}^\infty$ (see Jubin's "The Tangent Functor Monad and Foliations" at https://arxiv.org/abs/1401.0940): $T^0(M)=M,T^0(f)=f, T^i(M)=T(T^{i-1}(M)), T^i(f)=T(T^{i-1}(f))$.

---

Finally, going back to the local version, one could consider $C^{(q,\theta)}$-jets in tandem with $C^{(q,\theta)}$ functions (see Hirsch, Pugh & Shub's *Invariant Manifolds* (p.26) for a definition of Lipschitz jets; it's straightforward to adapt this to $C^{(q,\theta)}$-jets and develop the theory following Hirsch's *Differential Topology* (p.60)).

Comment: That's a great answer, thanks! Is there any reason to expect these notions to be equivalent, at least in some model spaces? And are you aware of Morrey-type inequalities (=embedding of Sobolev spaces into Hölder spaces) for any of these notions of Hölder continuity?