# $C^k$ functions for any $k\in\mathbb R$

Tags: continuity, holder-spaces

My question is simple: how is the space of $C^k$ functions defined for any $k\in\mathbb R$

Comment: $k$ times continuously differentiable  functions

Comment: http://mathworld.wolfram.com/C-kFunction.html

Comment: @infinity: Note that the the question says any real $k$, not necessarily a nonnegative integer.

Comment: For $k\in\mathbb{R}_{>0}$ see https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3324620/169085 (with $k=q+\alpha$).